# How to make Emacs transparent with i3-wm?

Tags: emacs, i3-wm, transparency

As instructed [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs) I added the following lines to my `emacs` configuration file:

```
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(85 . 50))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha . (85 . 50)))
```

But nothing changed. Every post that I checked on-line suggested that the above should work.

So I logged out of my `i3` windows manager and logged in using `Mate Desktop` and viola the transparency worked!

So question now is: what else do I have to do to make `emacs` transparent on `i3`?

EDIT: I am using `feh` to set up my desktop background.

p.s.: I have the gnome terminal transparent on `i3` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want this: https://github.com/vava/i3-emacs

Clone it into your emacs folder:

`git -C ~/.emacs.d/ clone https://github.com/vava/i3-emacs`

then add the following lines to your init.el:

```
;; i3 integration
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/i3-emacs")
(require 'i3)
(require 'i3-integration)
```

Note: This only seems to have an effect when emacs is run in a terminal, i.e. `emacs -nw`, although I have only just found it myself so not sure if it can apply to "GUI Emacs" too.